# Exponential random variables independency

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Assume that I have a random variable X~Exp(a) 
And a random variable Y which is defined: Y = X + W, whereas
Y~Gamma(2,a), For Gamma distribution definition: [Gamma distrubution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3top.png)
(r = 2, [Lambda]=a)

It is also known that if 2 random exponential variables with parameter a are independent, their sum is distributed as Gamma(2,a) 
The question is: if I know X and Y, can I deduct that X and W are independent? Is there a sentence that works in this direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take some $Z\sim Gamma\left(2,a\right)$ which is independent of $X$, and let $W = Z - X$. Then $Y = X + W = Z$, but

$$Cov\left(X,W\right) = Cov\left(X,Z\right) - Cov\left(X,X\right) = -Var\left(X\right).$$

Comment: Hi, X and Y (Z in your case) are not independent. In fact I know that X and W are independent, I'm looking for a way to prove it using the convolution theorem but the other way, as I wrote above.